# How to dynamically add pages to your site based on URL

Tags: php, html

Lets say for example I have http://www.example.com Now, I want to dynamically create a page for anything that is typed after `.com/` Say for instance if i typed http://www.example.com/page1-?3-30blablablablaFOOBAR then it would literally create a simple html file that way that page would be there even if it had never been created before.

I imagine this is possible somehow with PHP.

Comment: Do you use any content management system, or blogging tools such as WordPress, or MediaWiki?

Comment: You can do that with a combination of PHP and URL rewriting, but consider the consequence of the public being able to fill your hard drive with millions of files by incrementally calling URLs... Do you really want that?

Comment: Are you running Apache?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I considered this. There will be very specific conditions for the creation of the url. Trust me. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not advised to create page on demand, as people will create a lot HTMLs in your server.

Instead, you should use URL rewrite to handle such URLs and handle the URL in a centralized PHP. All created data should be managed by a content management system, and the data should be saved in database.

Comment: This is a good idea, I like the database idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at `mod_rewrite` rules.

You should be able to make a redirect to a PHP script with the given String `page1-?3-30blablablablaFOOBAR` as a parameter and then create the HTML page with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to "dynamically create a page" or handle the 404 page not found errors for which it sounds like you are trying to solve? If it's the latter, update your web server to redirect to a page of your choosing.

I'm assuming you are using Apache. If so, set the [ErrorDocument directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html) to a file you have already created to handle this scenario. It can be done within the server configuration, virtualhost definitions, or in an .htaccess file. From the docs:

> Custom error documents are configured using the ErrorDocument directive, which may be used in global, virtualhost, or directory context. It may be used in .htaccess files if AllowOverride is set to FileInfo.

```
ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry, our script crashed. Oh dear"
ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/crash-recover
ErrorDocument 500 http://error.example.com/server_error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not_found.html 
ErrorDocument 401 /subscription/how_to_subscribe.html
```

> The syntax of the ErrorDocument directive is:

```
ErrorDocument <3-digit-code> <action>
```

Comment: Not trying to handle 404 at all. Sorry mate.